# Transiting through the USA with a C1/D

Tags: usa, transit

I plan to travel to Jamaica after my contract I work on the ship. Can I use my C1/D to transit through the USA in New York to go to Jamaica?

Comment: Are you flying? Is that why you have tagged this 'US Airways'?

Comment: As explained in the linked question, you do not need to be traveling for work to use your transit/crewmember visa. You can also use it for your personal travel.